# First time Ubuntu user, Firefox not working

Tags: wireless

I am brand new to Linux, but I got an old tablet pc and installed lubuntu on it.   Everything seemed to go great but I cannot browse the Web with Firefox, it just says it can't find the server. 
The tablet is a computing motion le1600.

I googled around and found a few articles, but being new to the terminology, I didn't really understand.   When I connected to my router, I was unable to ping it.

Any advice on what to look at next?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Hi, how did you connect it to the Internet? Wifi or Ethernet cable?

Comment: so ... firefox is working but you have no internet connection ;) are you sure you set up internet correctly?

Comment: Sorry, it was late when I made the post.   I didn't do any additional configuration for the Internet settings after installing the psu.   Trying to use the wifi, which indicates that it's connected to the network, but can't ping the router or connect to the Internet. Is there more  configuration I missed?